# Laravel e o conceito MVC - onde coloco minhas classes/funções?

Tags: php, mvc, laravel-5

Ola. Sou novo no Laravel e na arquitetura MVC e tenho uma duvida conceitual.

No meu banco possuo um código(string), por exemplo "[paragrafo]". Vou transformar esta string em "`< p>meu paragrafo< /p>`" para ser exibida na view.
Essa transformação será através de algumas classes ou funções que, de acordo com o código retornado do banco irão gerar a respectiva string de saída (incluindo elementos html).

A duvida é: onde devo colocar estas minhas funções, dentro do modelo? ou devo criar helpers para usar nas views?

Muito obrigado e desculpem qualquer coisa. Abraços

Ps.: Estou usando o Laravel 5.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**José**, no Laravel, crie um arquivo `helpers.php` na sua pasta `app` e carregue-o automaticamente editando o `composer.json`:

```
"autoload": { 
"classmap": [ ... ],
 "psr-4": { "App\\": "app/"
 }, 
"files": [
 "app/helpers.php" // <---- ADICIONE AQUI
] },
```

Depois atualize o composer do projeto executando o comando:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

**Exemplo**

**`app/helpers.php`**

```
<?php

// ************************
// Criado em 05/02/2015
// Helper com utilidades criado por Felipe D.
// ************************

    /**
     * Retorna data e hora.
     *
     * @param   bool    $hora   Se vai retornar hora também
     * @return  string
     */
    function getData($hora)
    {
        // retorna, mas poderia ser "echo", whatever
        return ($hora ? date("d/m/Y H:i") : date("d/m/Y")) ; 
    }
```

**`app/Http/Controllers/DataController.php`**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Midia;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;


class DataController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        // Helpers podem ser chamados de QUALQUER lugar, 
        // inclusive pelas views, ex: usando {{ getData(true) }}
        $data = getData(true);

        // ou echo ou die ou carrega view, whatever
        return $data; 

    }
}
```

Como eu disse no comentário acima, `Helpers` podem ser chamados de **QUALQUER** lugar, inclusive pelas views. Veja como chamar a função `getData` acima dentro de uma `View` (usando Blade):

`<div>Data / Hora: {{ getData(true) }} </div>`

Comment: Ola Felipe, muito obrigado pela ajuda. Mas uma duvida continua, onde vou chamar essas funções que estão no arquivo helper? Crio accessors e mutators no modelo do banco para alterar a string ou envio a minha string para a view e acesso essas funções na própria view ou acesso as funções pelo controller e envio a string pra view ja modificada? Espero ter sido claro.

Comment: @JoséBadger, atualizei minha resposta. Agora não tem erro! haha

Comment: Entendi, cara, muito obrigado mesmo.